# Maximum number of integer solutions with some size constraints to bivariate polynomials?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, polynomials, arithmetic-geometry, diophantine-equations

Take a bivariate polynomial of total degree $d$ satisfying $d=d_x=d_y>1$ in $\mathbb Z[x,y]$ with coefficients bound in absolute value by $b$ ($d_x$ is $x$-degree and $d_y$ is $y$-degree).

> Given a $T>0$ and fixed $d=d_x=d_y>1$ what is the maximum number of integer roots that satisfy the condition if $(x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb Z$ is a root then
> $$|c_{i,j}||x_0|^{i}|y_0|^j<b|x_0|^{i}|y_0|^j<T$$
> holds at every $i,j\in\{0,1,\dots,d\}$ and $i+j\leq d=d_x=d_y$ where $c_{i,j}$ is the $x^{i}y^j$ coefficient of the polynomial (there could be other roots but we disregard them in the count)?

I am looking for dependence on $b,T$ for fixed $d_x,d_y$ and possibly extremal examples.

Are maximal family of examples known in literature or can be constructed?

Comment: If you take the polynomial $f(x,y) = (x-y)^d$, then $b = \binom{d}{\lfloor d/2 \rfloor}$ and your height condition becomes $|x| = |y| < T^{1/d}/\binom{d}{\lfloor d/2 \rfloor}$. This also bounds the number of solutions, and likely cannot be improved except for the constant. In general, the Bombieri-Pila bound I mentioned in the other post is probably as good as it gets. If you want better bounds then more information about the curve you are working with has to be considered, such as the genus.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao so number of solutions is $c_{d,\epsilon}T^{\frac1{d^2}+\epsilon}$ at some constant $c_{d,\epsilon}$ 1) in your example and 2) in my.problem too if the coefficients are generic? 3) How would genus affect the bound?

Comment: The number of solutions in my example is $O_d \left(T^{1/d}\right)$, not $O(T^{1/d^2})$... since there are $O(T^{1/d})$ choices for $x$ and $x$ determines $y$ (since $f(x,y) = 0$ if and only if $y = x$). Bombieri-Pila also gives $O_{d,\epsilon}(T^{1/d + \epsilon})$, not $O_{d,\epsilon}(T^{1/d^2 + \epsilon})$. If your curve has genus at least 1, then there will only be finitely many integer solutions by Siegel's theorem. If the genus is at least 2 then assuming the Bombieri-Lang conjecture there is a uniform bound on the number of solutions, depending only on the genus.

Comment: Does 'finite' depend on T or is it independent? What is the conjectural bound?

Comment: The bound is independent of $T$ (see Mordell's conjecture/Faltings' theorem). The precise nature of the uniform bound is unclear; work of Katz-Rabinoff-Zuerick-Brown suggests a polynomial bound in the degree is possible/likely.

Comment: Sorry your comment in other question says $O_{d,\epsilon}(t^{\frac1d + \epsilon})$ and $t$ here seems to be $T^{1/d}/\binom{d}{\lfloor d/2\rfloor}$ and so Bombieri-Pila seems to give $1/d^2$ in exponent. Am I wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115839/discussion-between-stanley-yao-xiao-and-1).

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao When you said $d=deg(f)=0\implies$ genus is $0$ did you refer to total degree $d_{total}$ or $\max(d_x,d_y)$ where $d_x$ is $x$-degree and $d_y$ is $y$-degree (note $d_{total}$ can be as large as $d_x+d_y$)?

Comment: If the degree is $1,2$ the curve is either a line or a conic, both have genus zero.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao Sorry my comment was does 'degree' refer to total degree or x-degree and y-degree? For example total degree of $x^2y^2$ is $4$ while $x$ and $y$ degree are $2$.

Comment: Total degree; the degree with respect to the variables is very uncommon.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao 1.) These are all arithmetic genus correct (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)#Algebraic_geometry)? 2.) Is $g_{geom}\leq g_{arith}$ always holding without exceptions?